# HTML5 Cache Manifest WSOD

Tags: html, browser-cache

When visiting my web app sometimes it takes a while for the cache manifest to update.
You can view the progress in the JS console but the page remains blank (wsod).
Is it possible to have a loading indicator or placeholder on the page until the manifest has updated?

Comment: Yes.  You just have to implement it, [here's the API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#application-cache-api).

Comment: Is this for initiating an update while the app is running? What seems to happen is that there is a cache update before the app is even loaded - I'm not sure if this can be prevented so that I can update the cache myself when the app is running.

Comment: If the app isn't loading then it's not cached.  There must be some other issue here.